# How to send twitter status update with umlauts?

Tags: api, twitter, status, diacritics

I can send a twitter tweet with the Twitter API. Every status update without german umlaut is accepted and I can see it in my twitter account.

Sending a tweet is done by sending a POST request to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Hello%20folks

When sending status=...  in the content body (with application/x-www-form-urlencoded) I get the error "Missing required parameter: status.". So sending in the url seems to be correct.

But when sending a german umlaut (diacritic) like ä, ö, ü, ß in the status=...%2C% parameter all I get is the unspecific error: Code 32, Message "Could not authenticate you.".

How can I send diacritics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We discovered a bug in LWP::Authen::Oauth.pm resulting in a broken encoding in the request sent to the Twitter API. After fixing that bug there's no problem anymore.